# Making a plot with small font using pdf() in r

Tags: r

I need to output a plot as a pdf of a certain size, which I am doing using the pdf() function:

```
library(ggplot2)
pdf(file="test12.pdf",width=3,height=3)
qplot(data=cars,x=speed,y=dist)+ggtitle("distance of cars as a function of speed")
dev.off()
```

Which results in part of the title being cut off:

[image]

I tried to reduce the point size from the default of 12 to 8:

```
pdf(file="test12.pdf",width=3,height=3,pointsize=8)
```

...Which makes a bit more of the p in speed viable. Further reducing pointsize to 6, 2, 1, or .1 has no noticeable effect. Increasing the pointsize does seem to noticeably increase the size of the text, however.

What's going on here? On the actual 3x3 inch pdf with default (or larger) pointsize, most of the text looks like it could be about 12+ point font. Is there some sort of undisclosed lower limit? How can I circumvent this? For my actual figure I'm guessing I will need something like 8 point font, which is on the small side but should still be perfectly readable.

Thanks!

Edit: while I could probably make everything fit by changing the size and positions of various elements, I think the graph would look visually cleanest if I could just scale down all the text. The title is the most obvious issue, but I'd also like to allot generally more space to the graphs and less to labels and such. If the only solution is to define sizes individually as I create my plot I can do that, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way just to make all text smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another approach, have you tried to adjust the font size with a theme?

theme(plot.title = element_text(size=6))

Comment: Using theme(text=element_text(size=6)) effectively does what I want. I'd still like to understand why I can't do the same thing within the pdf() call, but I suppose I shouldn't complain as long as I can make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to changing the font size of the main title is to add a newline break, so

```
plot(x,y,main="this is a really long title that won't fit on one line")
```

becomes

```
plot(x,y,main="Title that goes on the top line\nTitle that goes on the next line.")
```

Comment: Along with @user2583119's advice, this has helped me to reach a working solution. Thanks!